# Как добавить текст в элемент, в XML файл, по его id? С#

Tags: c#, xml

Вот мой код для добавления текста в XML, но он не работает. Подскажите, как это можно реализовать.

```cs
static void xmlAdd(string su)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("UserGrammar.xml");
    var itemName = doc.GetElementById("имя");
    itemName.InnerText = su;
    doc.Save("UserGrammar.xml");
}
```

А вот куда мне нужно добавить

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<grammar version="1.0" xml:lang="ru-RU" root="Подтверждение"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar" tag-format="semantics-ms/1.0">

  <rule id = "Подтверждение" scope = "public">
    <one-of>
       <item>
         <item>составитель</item>
         <item id="имя">
         </item>
      </item>  
    </one-of>
  </rule>
</grammar>
```

Comment: Модель DOM и класс XmlDocument считаются устаревшими. Лучше используйте Linq to Xml и классы XDocument/XElement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации по методу [XmlDocument.GetElementById](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.getelementbyid) сказано:

> The DOM implementation must have information which defines which attributes are of type ID. Although attributes of type ID can be defined in either XSD schemas or DTDs, this version of the product only supports those defined in DTDs. Attributes with the name "ID" are not of type ID unless so defined in the DTD. Implementations where it is unknown whether the attributes are of type ID are expected to return null.

Другими словами, вам нужно добавить схему, которая будет определять какой атрибут является ID для каждого XML элемента.

Например:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE grammar [
    <!ELEMENT grammar ANY>
    <!ELEMENT rule ANY>
    <!ELEMENT one-of ANY>
    <!ELEMENT item ANY>
    <!ATTLIST grammar version CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST grammar root CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST grammar tag-format CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST rule scope (public|private) #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST rule id ID #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST item id ID #IMPLIED>
]>
<grammar version="1.0" xml:lang="ru-RU" root="Подтверждение"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar" tag-format="semantics-ms/1.0">

    <rule id = "Подтверждение" scope = "public">
        <one-of>
            <item>
                <item>составитель</item>
                <item id="имя">
                </item>
            </item>
        </one-of>
    </rule>
</grammar>
```